# Set Size for Clustering to 1, Marker look like Cluster in here-maps

Tags: here-api

Is there a possibility to set the size for clustering to 1?
I want to have no "StandardMarkers".
So instead of having Markers and Clusters I like to have also Cluster with the Size of 1.
I tried to set the minPts but it was not working.

Any chances to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I draw the cluster marker with svg. (SvgParser)
You simply need to draw the Icon for the marker in the same way (with the same function).